# Whether there is a UDT backend for boost::asio?

Tags: c++, network-protocols, boost-asio, udp-data-transfer

Please, tell to me are whether exist UDT protocol backend for boost::asio?

UDT is a reliable UDP based application level data transport protocol for distributed data intensive applications over wide area high-speed networks. ( http://udt.sourceforge.net/index.html )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TCP, UDP, and ICMP are supported by Boost.Asio. Other protocols can be implemented by [extending](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/networking/protocols.html) the `Protocol` [type requirements](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/Protocol.html). There are [several threads](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.asio.user/4457) on the asio-users mailing list discussing adding support for SCTP, you may be able to use that as an example.

Comment: it's not green until checked :)

Answer (score 0):

This may sound like a shameless plug... But we are currently developing a UDT library based on boost.asio, so that you can have an stream_socket API based on UDP.

[Boost Asio Based UDT](https://github.com/securesocketfunneling/udt)

At this point, the library is functional (you can async_connect/ async_accept / async_write / async_read stream of bytes between client and server), but we do not support messaging yet. You can use every major Boost.Asio toolkit features with it (e.g. futures, coroutines, and even using TLS above UDT)

The library is still pretty young and we encounter performance issues due to timer precision as discussed [here](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/pull/24).