# UDT connection break during recv

Tags: boost, udp, boost-asio, udp-data-transfer

My code works fine in windows but when i compile it in mac and run it, the connection breaks during recv.

I am using UDT RENDEZVOUS mode to connect which works perfectly

```
bool rendezvous = true;
UDT::setsockopt(serv, 0, UDT_RENDEZVOUS, &rendezvous, sizeof(bool));
UDT::bind(serv,socket_.native());

if (UDT::ERROR == UDT::connect(serv, (sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)))
{
std::cout << UDT::getsockstate(serv);
}
```

i am binding a boost socket with udt socket.

here my connection breaks, and the error says, socket closed, non-exist

```
if (UDT::ERROR == (rs = UDT::recv(serv, data_read_TCP_Style.retdata() + rsize, size - rsize , 0)))
{
cout << "recv:" << UDT::getlasterror().getErrorMessage() << endl;
}
```

why does the connection breaks only during recv? what could possibly effecting the connection?

Comment: the asio library [does not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805544/whether-there-is-a-udt-backend-for-boostasio) natively support `UDT`, which library are you using?

Answer (score -1):

set rendezvous = false,maybe can solve this question.