# How to port code using boost::asio::stream_socket_service to newer versions of boost and asio?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, sctp

I'm trying to use the [asio-based UDT implementation](https://github.com/securesocketfunneling/udt) mentionned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805544/whether-there-is-a-udt-backend-for-boostasio), and it does not compile with the current version of Boost because it uses the old `boost::asio::stream_socket_service` which has disappeared from the asio API since Boost 1.67.

[This SCTP implementation](https://github.com/CompleteAndUtterGit/boost_asio_sctp) is another  example with the same issue.

These implementations basically define a class deriving from `boost::asio::basic_stream_socket` which is then passed as template parameter to `boost::asio::basic_stream_socket`.

Now that `boost::asio::basic_stream_socket` expects an executor, how should one port such implementations to the current asio API?

References:

- [stream_socket_service](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/stream_socket_service.html) in Boost 1.65
- [basic_stream_socket](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket.html) in Boost 1.65
- [basic_stream_socket](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket.html) in Boost 1.74

Comment: Tried creating an executor and passing it to them?